# Connecting Kendo UI Chart to SharePoint 2013 REST API

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, chart, telerik

I am a beginner to Telerik's Kendo UI Toolset and am having trouble connecting my UI Chart to our SharePoint's REST API. The chart displays when I debug the add in, in Visual Studio. However, the chart does not populate. I am trying to retrieve the "Problems" and "Month" column from the items in the list. Any ideas? All suggestions are welcomed!

```
<script>
    function createChart() {
        $("#chart").kendoChart({
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "OurSharePointDomain/_api/Web/Lists(guid'9f63673a-8a89-4e53-bfca-86f359d1ff09')/Items",
                        dataType: "json",
                        headers: {
                            "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
                        }
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    parse: function (response) {
                        var result = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i < response.d.results.length; i++) {
                            var item = {};
                            var Prob = new Prob(response.d.results[i]Problems);
                            var Mon = new Mon(response.d.results[i]Month);
                            result.push(item);
                        }
                        return result
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: "Kendo UI Chart That Won't Work"
            },
            legend: {
                position: "top"
            },
            seriesDefaults: {
                type: "area"
            },
            series: [{
                    field: "Prob",
                    name: "Problems"
                }
            }],
            categoryAxis: {
                field: "Mon",
                labels: {
                    rotation: -90
                },
                crosshair: {
                    visible: true
                }
            },
            valueAxis: {
                labels: {
                    format: "N0"
                },
                majorUnit: 5
            },
            tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                shared: true,
                format: "N0"
            }
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(createChart);
    $(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);
</script>
```

Comment: If the answer was helpful could you remove it from the SO unanswered list, by marking it as answered, tnx

Answer (score 0):

This is plain JavaScript programming error.. nothing to do with SP or Kendo

Learn to use the F12 Console

Or read your own code:

```
 var result = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < response.d.results.length; i++) {
     var item = {};
     var Prob = new Prob(response.d.results[i]Problems);
     var Mon = new Mon(response.d.results[i]Month);
     result.push(item);
 }
 return result
```

What are the items in the result list?

1. you are creating an error with: `[i]Problems`
2. You are not putting anything IN the item object

FYI, this is less error prone:

```
return result = response.d.results.map(function(item){
    return {
             Prob:item.Problems,
             Mon:item.Month
           }
});
```